# Veröffentlichung aufheben, zurückziehen, aktualisieren

Tags: phrase

In einer Applikation ist es möglich eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit / ein wissenschaftliches Dokument zu veröffentlichen. Dazu gibt es einen Button mit dem Text **"Veröffentlichen"**.

Falls es welche Änderungen gibt und das Dokument bereits veröffentlicht wurde, kann man mit einem entsprechenden Button die **"Veröffentlichung Aktualisieren"**

Nun soll es möglich sein die **"Veröffentlichung zurückzuziehen"**. Allerdings scheint das Wort "zurückziehen" für viele viel zu negativ zu sein.
Ich bin kein Muttersprachler und stehe ein wenig auf dem Schlauch...

Hat jemand einen Vorschlag wie man die drei Buttons vielleicht besser, verständlicher, intuitiver benennen kann?

Comment: Ich sehe dieses Thema ein bisschen paradox: ist es einmal veröffentlicht - besonders im Internet - so sehe ich ein Problem darin, diese Veröffentlichung zurückzuziehen... Aber ich versteh, denke ich, warum es bei dieser Applikation gehen soll.

Comment: Zumindest ist es inkonsequent, 'zurückziehen' klein zu schreiben, 'aktualisieren' und 'veröffentlichen' aber groß. Ich empfinde 'zurückziehen' als absolut neutral. Widerrufen hätte dagegen etwas von Gallileo Gallilei.

Comment: Warum nicht "Veröffentlichung löschen"?

Comment: Ich kann nicht gut nachvollziehen, warum "zurückziehen" negativ belegt sein sollte. Ein _taktischer Rückzug_ rettet z.B. schließlich Leben und ermöglicht es, später doch noch zu gewinnen.

Comment: Bei den bundesdeutschen öffentlich-rechtlichen Sendern heißt ein ähnlicher Vorgang [_Depublizieren_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depublizieren) – nicht unbedingt nachahmenswert. Eingedeutscht wäre das vielleicht _?entöffentlichen_ oder halt _verstecken_. Standards u.a. werden _zurückgezogen_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie wäre es mit **Veröffentlichung zurücknehmen** oder **Veröffentlichung entfernen**?
Im weiten Sinne würde vielleicht auch **ausblenden**, **verstecken** oder **deaktivieren** funktionieren.

Da die Tat einer Zurücknahme oder Ablehnung meist mit negativen Worten verknüpft ist, wird es schwer sein einen Ausdruck zu finden, den keiner als negativ empfindet.

Comment: Kommt auf die Art der Anwendung an: falls die Veröffentlichung von der Plattform wirklich gelöscht wird und keiner mehr drauf zugreifen kann, dann "Entfernen" oder "Löschen". Falls man immer noch sehen kann, dass mal etwas veröffentlicht wurde (z. B. Statuswechsel, Dokument nicht mehr aufrufbar), würde ich "Zurücknehmen" wählen.